# How do you set an array instance variable to a specific set of data?

Tags: java, arrays, instance-variables

```
public class Sentencegenerator {
private String[] subjects;
private String[] verbs; 
private String[] directObjects;

public Sentencegenerator(){
    subjects = {"Cat", "Dog", "Joe", "Teacher", "Policeman", "Doctor", "Dick"};
    verbs = {"eats", "reads", "cums", "farts", "poops", "stabs", "cries"};
    directObjects = {"book", "sticker", "fish", "man", "chiwawa", "marker", "cheese"};
}

public Sentencegenerator(String[] mySubjects, String[] myVerbs, String[]    myDirectObjects){
    subjects = mySubjects;
    verbs = myVerbs;
    directObjects = myDirectObjects;
}
```

I know you can only create array constants when you initialize an array, but is there a way I can make an array instance variable and then make a constructor that has its own constants?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by constructor having it's own constants?

Comment: The array constants, for example, in subjects are Cat, Dog, Joe, Teacher, Policeman, Doctor, and Dick. I am getting a compiler error because you can't create array constants after you created the array. I want to know a way I can still make a constructor with these constants, but I am hesitant to just create the variables in the constructor because I am not sure if that is allowed in Java convention. If that is the only way, however, then so be it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to instantiate an array to a constant array:

```
String[] subjects = {"Cat", "Dog", "Joe", "Teacher", "Policeman", "Doctor", "Dick"};
```

or:

```
String[] subjects;
subjects = new String[] {"Cat", "Dog", "Joe", "Teacher", "Policeman", "Doctor", "Dick"};
```

In your constructor, you need to use the latter (note the `new String[]` part).